# A question about integral extension and ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I want to resolve the following exercise:

Let $A \subseteq B$ an integral extension of commutative rings. Show that if $\mathfrak{a}$ is a proper ideal of $A$, then $\mathfrak{a}B$ is a proper ideal of $B$.

I know there is $a \in A-\mathfrak{a}$, can I prove that $a \in B-\mathfrak{a}B$?

The autor says I need to use determinant trick, but I can't see it.

Comment: What is determinant trick ? I am no expert at this sorry.
But I think the determinant is the norm here and you show that this element is also a norm of the the proper ideal of B ...

Comment: Well, it seems easier to use lying over theorem, but I do not know what the author was thinking with this hint .

Comment: It would be good to say where you found this - please add that to your post with an [edit].